# Conditional Cast warning becomes initializer for conditional binding must have Optional error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to delete a tableView Cell with the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate. I'm using this if statement in the TabbleView commit function.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        if let person = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath){
            fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext.delete(person)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:
Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Person'

If I cast the person as an optinoal Person

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        if let person = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath) as? Person{
            fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext.delete(person)
        }
    }
}
```

I get this warning:
Non-optional expression of type 'Person' used in a check for optionals

It seems to be working with the warning, but I would like to clear this up so that I better understand what is going on.

Comment: `object(at:)` doesn't return an optional so you shouldn't be using it with an if let.

Comment: Martin, where is the duplicate question, I did a search and couldn't find what you are referring to.

Comment: Have a look at the top of your question: "This question already has an answer here: " ... followed by a link. You'll find more similar question in the "Related" section.

Comment: Dan, what would I use, I tried objectAtIndexpath, but xcode just changes it to what I have above.

Comment: Martin, Thanks somehow I didn't see that new section!

Comment: Use what you were originally using, just use a regular `let` instead of an `if let`